# how to show original $index for array returned from Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase

I am having a trouble now.
  Everything is going smoothly. I use ngRepeat to show the lists which are Array from Firebase with $asArray() function. I also use "reverse" filter so that when I have a new item, it appears to the top. Now I want to add index for each item, and surely it returns the indexes for filtered array. 
  I want to know is there any way to show the origin index for each item in the array (before I filter with "reverse" filter) to show with ngRepeat? 
My expected code like:

```
    <ul ng-repeat="list in filtered=(lists | filter:query) | reverse">
       <li>{{origin_index_from_lists}} - {{list.name}}</li>
    </ul>
```

filter: reverse is returned from **lists.slice().reverse();**

Comment: What significance to the original indexes have? They are fluid, array indices with no connection or bearing on the data, so it's likely that you are solving an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) and there is probably a better approach. Explaining the use case will be helpful. Also, what is this data structure exactly? A list of lists? More context would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get the data in order, as soon as you get it iterate through it and attach an `index` parameter to each object with the corresponding index. Like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lists; i++) {
    lists[i].index = i;
}
```